# I can't make jack server to work with pulseaudio, any quick fix?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, jack

My pulse audio mixer looks like this:

[image]

May be this qjackctl log can help:

```
16:22:20.805 Statistics reset.
16:22:20.806 ALSA connection change.
16:22:20.807 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
16:22:20.931 ALSA connection graph change.
16:22:29.037 D-BUS: JACK server is starting...
16:22:29.038 D-BUS: JACK server was started (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Tue Nov  9 16:22:28 2021: Starting jack server...
Tue Nov  9 16:22:28 2021: JACK server starting in non-realtime mode
Tue Nov  9 16:22:28 2021: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Tue Nov  9 16:22:28 2021: ERROR: Cannot lock down 107341340 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: Acquired audio card Audio0
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|96000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: configuring for 96000Hz, period = 1024 frames (10.7 ms), buffer = 2 periods
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_1'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: New client 'system' with PID 0
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_2'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: New client 'PulseAudio JACK Sink' with PID 671
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: Connecting 'PulseAudio JACK Sink:front-left' to 'system:playback_1'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: Connecting 'PulseAudio JACK Sink:front-right' to 'system:playback_2'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: New client 'PulseAudio JACK Source' with PID 671
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Source was not finished, state = Triggered
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: Connecting 'system:capture_1' to 'PulseAudio JACK Source:front-left'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:29 2021: Connecting 'system:capture_2' to 'PulseAudio JACK Source:front-right'
Tue Nov  9 16:22:30 2021: Saving settings to "/home/human/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
16:22:31.083 JACK connection change.
16:22:31.085 Statistics reset.
16:22:31.102 Client activated.
16:22:31.102 Patchbay deactivated.
16:22:31.115 JACK connection graph change.
Cannot lock down 107341340 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Tue Nov  9 16:22:31 2021: New client 'qjackctl' with PID 108656
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```bsh
killall -9 pulseadio
```

or

```bsh
systemctl restart --user pulseaudio
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.